# SBT `dependsOn` Per-configuration dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Build with two projects in it. 
I want to make the root project classpath dependent on subProject, but only in certain configuration. Simplified project's config:

Subproject:

```
object HttpBuild{

  import Dependencies._

 lazy val http: Project = Project(
  "http",
  file("http"),
  settings =
  CommonSettings.settings ++
    Seq(
      version := "0.2-SNAPSHOT",
      crossPaths := false,
      libraryDependencies ++= akkaActor +: spray) ++
    Packaging.defaultPackageSettings
 )}
```

Root:

```
object RootBuild extends Build {
import HttpBuild._
lazy val http = HttpBuild.http

lazy val MyConfig = config("myconfig") extend Compile

private val defaultSettings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings

lazy val api = Project("root", file("."))
.configs(MyConfig)
.settings(defaultSettings: _*)
.dependsOn(HttpBuild.http % MyConfig)
}
```

Now if i type `myconfig:compile` i want to have my root project compiled with subproject, but it doesn't seem to happen.

If i leave dependencies like this `dependsOn(HttpBuild.http)`, it compiles, but it happens every time, no matter which configuration i use.

Comment: You don't want to have 2 objects extending Build. There should only be 1 build.

Comment: @DaleWijnand True, thank you. I've fixed the description

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this example](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Advanced-Configurations-Example.html). I'm not an expert here, but comparing with your code above, the difference seems to be

- that a `CustomCompile` configuration is defined and used as `classpathConfiguration in Common := CustomCompile`
- that the dependency is indirect `http % "compile->myconfig"`

Perhaps try to get closer to that example.